# wordpress show popular posts based on facebook comments

Tags: wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

So what i have in mind is showing a list with most popular posts based on how many facebook comments they have. I already managed to make a function that counts based facebook graph how many comments a post has, but i am having problem with the query:

```
function fb_comment_count() {
global $post;
$url = get_permalink($post->ID);

$filecontent = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);
$json = json_decode($filecontent);
$count = $json->$url->comments;
if ($count == 0 || !isset($count)) {
    $count = 0;
} ?>

<?php if ($count == 0) { ?>
         <span>No comment</span>
<?php } elseif ($count == 1) { ?>
         <span>One Comment</span>
<?php } elseif ($count > 1 ) { ?>
         <span><?php echo $count; ?> Comments</span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?  Are there any errors?

Comment: no errors. i just don't know how to make the query to show, lets say 5 posts with most facebook comments

Comment: @ciprian, do you store the comments count somewhere into database or wordpress post meta? If not it'll gonna be VERY slow to fetch comments count for all your posts to only display most commented...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to store number of comments to [post meta-data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) so you'll be able to use it for sorting later.

BTW, your function will not work due to difference in response format you use and the real response. (number of comments is present in `response->comments->count` and not in `response->comments`). Also you may wish to use `fields=comments` to limit the response to only include details about comments without all the rest of data or using FQL query to retrieve only count of comments:

```
SELECT commentsbox_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = 'POST_URL'
```

The flow as I see it may be so:

- Store number of comments within post-meta
- Update number of comments calling `fb_comment_count` once post is viewed
- Use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) with `meta_key` to change the defaults.

```php
function fb_comment_count() {
  global $post;
  $url = get_permalink($post->ID);

  $query = "SELECT commentsbox_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = '{$url}'";
  $responseText = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q='.$query);
  $responseJson = json_decode($responseText);

  $commenteCount = $responseJson->data->commentsbox_count;
  update_post_meta($post->ID, 'facebook_comments_count, $commenteCount);
  // ...
}
```

Once your posts have `facebook_comments_count` [meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) you can use `query_posts` in [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop):

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=5&meta_key=facebook_comments_count&orderby=meta_value&order=DESC')
```

Comment: i changed `commentsbox_count` to `comment_count` then it worked for me

Comment: where would this code go? in functions.php?  also could you change update_post_meta( 7, 'fruit', 'banana' ) to add_post_meta( 7, 'fruit', 'banana', true ) || update_post_meta( 7, 'fruit', 'banana' );

Answer (score 1):

You will want to get to HTTP GET to `http://graph.facebook.com/comments?ids=` and it will returns an object with a data property.  That data property will be a array of comment objects (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/)

For example:

`http://graph.facebook.com/comments?ids=http://www.stackoverflow.com/`

```
{
   "http://www.stackoverflow.com/": {
      "data": [
         {
            "id": "450042939888_21515527",
            "from": {
               "name": "Anidhya Ahuja",
               "id": "1172382999"
            },
            "message": "abc",
            "created_time": "2011-10-11T13:55:15+0000"
         },
         {
            "id": "450042939888_21515536",
            "from": {
               "name": "Anidhya Ahuja",
               "id": "1172382999"
            },
            "message": "wass",
            "created_time": "2011-10-11T13:55:48+0000"
         }
      ],
      "paging": {
         "next": "http://graph.facebook.com/comments?ids=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.stackoverflow.com\u00252F&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=450042939888_21515536"
      }
   }
}
```